# How to estimate gaussian distribution parameters using MLE in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, pattern-recognition

I've got a set of data with Gaussian distribution, here is a histogram that shows how they actually look like:

[image: Gaussian distribution]

I have to classify these data into two class using bayesian classifier, which I'm doing that using `sklearn` and it's working fine. However as a part of job I have to estimate the distribution parameters of data (σ, μ) using MLE and use them in my classifier.

So is there any python library or pseudo code that can estimate the gaussian distribution parameters using maximum likelihood method so I can use the estimated values in my classifier?

I'm looking for something like `mle(data,'distribution',dist)` from Matlab.

```
phat = mle(MPG,'distribution','burr')
phat =
34.6447    3.7898    3.5722
```

Comment: Do you insist on calling a library? Because it would be a trivial numpy 2-liner ;-)

Comment: @dedObed If it's clear enough, I'm good with that...

Comment: Ok, answer incoming. Just to make sure... you only care about 1-dimensial data?

Comment: @dedObed I forgot about that... my data are actually images with reduced dimensional (15).

Comment: Now it becomes more interesting :-) So it is multidimensional data... do you want to model it by a Gaussian with a diagonal covariance or a full covariance one?

Comment: I'm suffering from lack of knowledge in this area... I guess it should be full.

Comment: @dedObed Actually I have to estimate the parameters for to set of data then use them with a bayesian classifier to classifier these two set.

Comment: Which kinda makes my answer irrelevant. So please review your question, write down what you really want achieve. Because for Naive Bayes with Gaussians, you can e.g. go with scikit-learn (sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB).

Comment: @dedObed That's what I'm doing right now, however I should rewrite it and use the estimated values...  I'll try to edit the question and make it more clear.

Comment: Looking forward to your updated question. Anyway, if you "should rewrite" then you should do some reading first. "Just running" classification algorithms will shoot you in the leg sooner or later. For sure.

Answer (score 2):

So as your data is multidimensional (D, in your case specifically D=15), you need to model the mean of the data (D dimensional) and the covariance (D^2 dimensional).

You can easily implement it using numpy as follows

```
import numpy as np

def gaussian_mle(data):                                                                                                                                                                               
    mu = data.mean(axis=0)                                                                                                                                                                            
    var = (data-mu).T @ (data-mu) / data.shape[0] #  this is slightly suboptimal, but instructive

    return mu, var
```

To see that it works, lets run it on some artificial data:

```
mean = [1.0, 3.14]                                                                                                                                                                                    
cov = [[2.0, 0.5], [0.5, 10]]                                                                                                                                                                         
data = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 10000)                                                                                                                                                

print(gaussian_mle(data))
```

Which gives us, after custom formating (as we sample randomly, results may differ slightly):

```
(
    array([1.00981014, 3.1217965 ]), #  sample mean
    array([[2.0266404 , 0.43036865], 
           [0.43036865, 9.87599803]]) #  sample covariance
)
```